# OpenGL runs randomly

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

My application that I made previously ran without any problems. Now when I made some adjustments to it, it sometimes runs and sometimes doesn't. When reboot the computer theres a 50% chance that the program works without any problems, but if it doesn't it won't until I reboot. So it has something to do with rebooting. Even the fully functioning previous versions don't run when the current version doesn't run. When the current version runs the other previous versions run too.

The program runs all the way up to the `glfwCreateWindow()`and then triggers a breakpoint.

Call stack:

`-> vrfcore.dll!_VerifierStopMessageEx()
    vfbasics.dll!_AVrfpRTIInitializeCriticalSection()
    nvdlist.dll`

Code:

```
glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Window", NULL, NULL); // This line triggers a breakpoint
```

Edit:

Just found out that if the exe file is called for example program.exe (the original name) it crashes. And if I change the name it runs no problem. Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: *So it has something to do with rebooting* -- C++ has something called *undefined behavior*, where you have bugs in your program that causes it.  It has nothing to do with booting or rebooting.   It could be as simple as an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Did genpfault's answer solve your problem? If so don't edit the answer into your question

Comment: You say it has to be with "rebooting your computer".  Chances are it has nothing to do with rebooting the computer.  You should actually figure out what is wrong with the program or the "adjustments" you added.  Your program may have had bugs from the start, and the adjustment now exposed those bugs.

Comment: Is it possible that it’s already running and because of that I can run it only if it has a different name. (The previous ones that worked had a different name)